# Wrong <li> tag behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying create basic web "to do list".
The problem is that after I am adding manually todos and click them they just ignore "text-decoration: line-through;" and I can't see the line crossing my todo box.

I compared the two applied with .lineThrough class li's and the difference is that manually added li got automatically applied this classes:

```
.far {  
li:nth-child(2n) {  
   font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';  
   font-weight: 400;    
}   
.fa, .fas, .far, .fal, .fad, .fab { 
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;  
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   display: inline-block;   
   font-style: normal;  
   font-variant: normal;    
   text-rendering: auto;    
   line-height: 1;

}
user agent stylesheet   
i { 
   font-style: italic;  
   background: white;
}
```

What could be the problem?

My .js file:

```js
$("i").on("click",function (){  
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500,function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
})


$("ul").on("click","li",function (){
    $(this).toggleClass("lineThrough");    
})


$("#plusBtn").on("click",function(){
    var newTodo = $("#searchBox").val();
    var newTodo = "<li> <i class='far fa-trash-alt'> </i>"+newTodo+"</li>"
    if($("#searchBox").val() != ""){
        $("#toDos").append(newTodo);
        $("#searchBox").val("");
    }
})


$("#searchBox").on("keypress",function(k){ 
    if(k.which == 13){
        var newTodo = $("#searchBox").val();
        var newTodo = "<li><i class='far fa-trash-alt'>"+newTodo+"</i></li>"
        if($("#searchBox").val() != ""){
            $("#toDos").append(newTodo);
            $(this).val("");
        }
    }
})
My .css file
```

```css
body{
    background-image:linear-gradient(to right, #076585 ,#fff); ;

}

#table{

    width: 350px;  
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px   #79777767;

}
#todoTitle{
    background: rgb(88, 88, 214);
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 25px;

}

#plusBtn{
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 45px;
    float: right;
    line-height: 45px;
    outline: none;
}

#searchBox{
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 45px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: gray;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#toDos{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    
    
}

li{
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    padding-left: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: gray;
    
}

li:nth-child(2n){
    background: white;

}

.lineThrough{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: rgb(182, 179, 179);
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>TO DO LIST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tdl_css.css">
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gupter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id = "table">
       <div id = "todoTitle">TO-DO LIST
            <button id= "plusBtn">+</button>
       </div>
       <input type="text" id = "searchBox" placeholder="Add New Todo"></input>
        
       <ul id="toDos">
        <li> <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>safsdfsdf</li>
        <li> <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>sasdddsdfsdfsdf</li>
       </ul>


    </div>





    <script type = "text/javascript" src="tdl_js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unable to replicate - your code appears to work fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/nw72zag5/

Comment: Added the full code https://jsfiddle.net/TyphooNN/1vfwdeyc/3/

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] in the question itself, not only on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon has `<>` on it, or Ctrl+M in editor) to do pretty much everything jsFiddle can, here.

Comment: @SergeyArenzon your own fiddle seems to also work, unless I'm not understanding the issue.

Comment: Rory McCrossan, if you adds new "todo" and try to tick it off by clicking on its text it wont be ticked of as the built in todos.
the "text-decoration: line-through;" isnt really applied on new todos

Comment: It works if I click the plus after entering a new todo, but not when I enter one and hit enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the new value is inserted inside `<i>` tag instead of `<li>` tag like `<li><i class='far fa-trash-alt'>Value</i></li>` instead of `<li><i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i>value</li>`.

Please insert the value at proper place and it will work fine. It might be unintentional mistake because for #plusBtn you have done correctly but missed for #searchBox.

Have fixed for you. Please verify

```js
$("i").on("click",function (){  
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500,function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
})


$("ul").on("click","li",function (){
    $(this).toggleClass("lineThrough");    
})


$("#plusBtn").on("click",function(){
    var newTodo = $("#searchBox").val();
    var newTodo = "<li> <i class='far fa-trash-alt'> </i>"+newTodo+"</li>"
    if($("#searchBox").val() != ""){
        $("#toDos").append(newTodo);
        $("#searchBox").val("");
    }
})


$("#searchBox").on("keypress",function(k){ 
    if(k.which == 13){
        var newTodo = $("#searchBox").val();
        var newTodo = "<li><i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i>"+newTodo+"</li>" //Check here fixed
        if($("#searchBox").val() != ""){
            $("#toDos").append(newTodo);
            $(this).val("");
        }
    }
})
```

```css
body{
    background-image:linear-gradient(to right, #076585 ,#fff); ;

}

#table{

    width: 350px;  
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px   #79777767;

}
#todoTitle{
    background: rgb(88, 88, 214);
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 25px;

}

#plusBtn{
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 45px;
    float: right;
    line-height: 45px;
    outline: none;
}

#searchBox{
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 45px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: gray;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#toDos{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    
    
}

li{
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    padding-left: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: gray;
    
}

li:nth-child(2n){
    background: white;

}

.lineThrough{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: rgb(182, 179, 179);
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>TO DO LIST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tdl_css.css">
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gupter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id = "table">
       <div id = "todoTitle">TO-DO LIST
            <button id= "plusBtn">+</button>
       </div>
       <input type="text" id = "searchBox" placeholder="Add New Todo"></input>
        
       <ul id="toDos">
        <li> <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>safsdfsdf</li>
        <li> <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>sasdddsdfsdfsdf</li>
       </ul>


    </div>





    <script type = "text/javascript" src="tdl_js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps. Please revert for any clarifications.